# Extract every other column and line graph in Javascript + d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am very new to Javascript and D3. So maybe a very simple question.

I have a csv file that I need to import.
The columns are the following.
Date, Value A(score), Value A(rank), Value B(score), Value B(rank), ....Value Z(rank).

I need to graph this using D3 for Date vs Value A(score) and Value B(score).

I am currently using the code below.

```
const dataset = d3.csv("boardgame_ratings.csv")

        dataset1.then(function(data){
        const slices = data.columns.slice(1).map(function(id){
            return {
            id: id,
            values: data.map(function(d){
                return {
                date: timeConv(d.date),
                measurement: +d[id]
                };
            })
            };
        })
```

I omit the actual graphing, because I do not have issue with that.

What I am having an issue is that I need to graph only the "score" section. Not the "rank" section. the code that I wrote graphs every column.

I am having trouble because JS is asynchronous.
How would I implement the following?

1. Extract the "score" only and date columns from the CSV file.
2. Declare the new data as dataset.
3. implement the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say the problem here is your code for drawing the chart (as you mentioned, *"the code that I wrote graphs every column"*). This is not ideal because you need to have control of what you draw, so a quick fix would be creating an array of keys telling what columns to use. Also, filtering out columns is unnecessary because when you fetch the CSV you're getting the whole file: if you don't need some columns, just ignore them. Therefore, filtering them out will only add burden to the browser.

All that said, `d3.csv` accepts a row function, so eliminating some columns is trivial:

```
const dataset = d3.csv("boardgame_ratings.csv", d => ({foo: d.foo, bar: d.bar}));
```

Here I'm keeping only the columns `foo` and `bar`, ignoring all other columns.